# Error calling Controller Method from View - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm getting this error calling the Controller Method getListCategories() from the view.

> TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
>       at Function.keys (native)
>       at extend (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:412:25)
>       at Function.angular.module.provider.$get.Resource.(anonymous function) (app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:575:15)
>       at Scope.$scope.getListCategories (app/shoppinglists/shoppinglists.js:17:69)
>       at $parseFunctionCall (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12332:18)
>       at Object.expressionInputWatch (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12735:31)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14217:40)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14488:24)
>       at done (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9646:47)
>       at completeRequest (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9836:7) (22:31:11:425 | error)

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, so any suggestion is more than welcome.

**Service**

```
shoppingListService.factory('ShoppingLists', function ($resource) {
var factory = {
    getShoppingLists: $resource('http://localhost:8080/ShoppingListBackend/webresources/shoppinglists', {}, {
        all: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    }),
    getCategories : $resource('http://localhost:8080/ShoppingListBackend/webresources/shoppinglists/getcategories/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
        byId: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    })
};
return factory; });
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ShoppingListController', function ($scope, ShoppingLists) {
    $scope.shoppinglists = ShoppingLists.getShoppingLists.all();

    $scope.getListCategories = function (id) {
        $scope.listCategories = ShoppingLists.getCategories.byId(id);
    };
});
```

**View**

```
<div id="card" ng-controller="ShoppingListController" ng-repeat="list in shoppinglists">
    <div id="card_title">{{list.title}}</div>
<div id="card_subtitle"><span>{{getListCategories(list.id)}}</span></div>
<div id="card_body">
    <input type="checkbox" id="item_checked">
    <label for="item_checked">Toilet Paper</label>
</div>
```

Comment: and what happens on server console ? what is response code ?

Comment: Jigar Joshi, I don't understand your questions, what do you mean by response code?

Comment: @JigarJoshi How do I see the HTTP Response Code? The view shows this "{{getListCategories(list.id)}}" instead of the Method result.

Comment: make a GET request with your browser and see

Comment: A GET request to the RESTful Service works.
http://localhost:8080/ShoppingListBackend/webresources/shoppinglists/getcategories/1

Comment: then this is angular question not for Java, I will move it